# Error downloading root certificate on iPad

Tags: java, ios, ipad, wso2, wso2-iot

I'm unable to download the root certificate of [WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/) 1.1.0 on iPad.

```
[2014-06-25 15:27:26,098] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13) (/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag#2)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13) (/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag#2)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:447)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13) (/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag#2)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c0._c_script_0(/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag:2)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c0.call(/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c0.call(/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c0.exec(/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.executeScript(WebAppManager.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.require(WebAppManager.java:323)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3767)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3755)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2346)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c3._c_anonymous_1(/emm/modules/iosemm.js:13)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c3.call(/emm/modules/iosemm.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c3._c_script_0(/emm/modules/iosemm.js:1)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c3.call(/emm/modules/iosemm.js)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c3.exec(/emm/modules/iosemm.js)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    ... 89 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager does not pack iOS related components. This is due to the closed nature of Apple MDM protocol. If you need this certificates and relevant component files you will have to make a csr request from [this link](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/csr/). Further reading can be found at [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Generating+a+MDM+APNS+Certificate).

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of iPhone Configuration Utility (ICU) from Apple.

Use that to generate a configuration profile that contains the certificates you wish to install (you can ignore everything else in ICU... just create a specific profile with just the certificates).  Then you can deploy via :

1. Saving the profile and emailing it
2. Saving the profile and making it available for download through a website
3. Plugging in an iPhone/iPad and pushing the profile to it (don't forget to turn off auto sync in iTunes if you're planning to do this for other people's devices !).

Note that this answer is not specific to "WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager" (infact I've never used it).  Its just a generic answer about how to easily install certificates on iPhones.